# Android : how i can get recent opened window?

Tags: android

How can I get a package of running / current application? I looked at a lot of topics, but not one has helped me yet.

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean the package name of your own App, if so, you can get it with the following method:

```
context.applicationContext.packageName
```

You can get more info like the version name with somethin like this:

```
context.applicationContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.applicationContext.packageName, 0)
providerPackageInfo.versionName.toString()
```

Hope it helps